# How can a thread (recevier) write request & response to an file while thread(sender) will send only request?

Tags: java

We have an requirement in which it causes an design constraint and it is show stopper. Here it is,

1. Sender thread will put requests into the messaging queue. Input source is a text file that contains 10 million requests.
2. Recevier thread polls the responses from another queue and write it onto another output file.

Design Constraint:

1. Recevier thread has to write the request and response onto output file. **How this is possible ?**
2. No Database should be used
3. Caching the request before sending and updating it after corresponding response has been recevied cannot be used because of performance bottleneck.
4. In few cases, timeout occurs if the response is delayed very long time.

Please advice.

Comment: Do requests and responses have some sort of unique identifier?

Comment: Why are the queues at (1) and (2) different?

Comment: @EJP that's probably an optimization to increase throughput. By handling responses asynchronously a stalled request handling won't delay other request/response pairs.

Comment: Hari, if a question you posted is answered adequately you should accept the answer to acknowledge this. I notice you have not accepted any answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just one Receiver thread, it is guaranteed that only one request will be processed at a time.

Having the sender thread write the request and response is probably not the most elegant design, but you could certainly have the Receiver thread write the {request, response} tuple. The Receiver thread could also write the request before it starts processing and the response after it is done. It will have the same result as what you are aiming for.

If you give out more details about your design, I can provide you with more design help.

Comment: Multiple request handlers might be reading the 'messaging queue' in parallel and putting their responses on the 'other queue' in an unpredictable order.

Comment: The final implementation will depend on the number of producer/consumer threads - agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas for solutions:

The receiver thread could look up the original request from the file. This requires responses to have some form of unique correlation id.

The handler threads could add the original request to the response. This makes message size bigger but avoids the need of a correlation id. It also requires configuration/code changes to be made to the handler threads.

The sender thread could duplicate the request on a secondary local queue. The receiver thread looks up the original request for a received response on this queue. Responses might not be received in the same order as the requests were sent so the receiver thread might need to 'walk the queue' to find the request which is not very efficient.

The last solution comprises a form of caching. You state this is not allowed due to performance reasons. I don't understand exactly why though. Local caching is fast and there  should not be a large amount of queued requests in the cache at any given time since the sending, handling and receiving are all asynchronous.

Comment: Dear Koster,Thanks for the solution. Anyways, we have decided to use the last solution of yours. Let me see how it impacts during testing. We will read few requests into java queue where every threads polls for a request from the queue, puts it in messaging queue and wait for response. But in this case, the performance bottle neck is the same thread has to wait for the response with no time out option enabled.